# Apache Cordova: CSP Error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps

I have a problem with the Android 5.0 Lollipop and Google Maps Api, i have an CSP Error of unsafe-eval.

Here is the Error:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/22/7/intl/es_ALL/main.js:65
>
> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * 'unsafe-inline'".

The Code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Inside my config.xml i have this:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
```

I have no problems with Android 4.x but just only with 5.x, i know it's because of the Chromium Webview but i can't use the Google Maps because of this error.

What can i do to fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try refactoring your Content-Security-Policy meta tag a little, I have the following working in a Cordova 5 / Android 5 app that uses Google Maps (; positions are different from yours:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Comment: I have this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/22/7/intl/es_ALL/main.js:65
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * 'unsafe-inline'".
Still not working

Comment: Is inline scripts the problem ? I may try put all my code on a .js

Comment: Try a ; between default-src * and 'unsafe-inline' as per my posted Content-Security-Policy example.  You may also need to wait for the Cordova deviceready event before running scrips so inline script may be a contributing factor but try changing the Content-Security-Policy first.